# Python _Scrapy : FakeUserAgentError: Maximum amount of retries reached

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Python 2.7.17
Scrapy==1.1.1
fake-useragent==0.1.7

Tried with upgrading fake-useragent and ua = UserAgent(verify_ssl=False) but still getting same error please help in this issue.

Error : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/axisrooms/.virtualenvs/ge_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "/home/axisrooms/.virtualenvs/ge_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 37, in process_request
response = yield method(request=request, spider=spider)
File "/home/axisrooms/projects/golden-eye/spiders/booking/booking/middlewares.py", line 35, in process_request
ua = UserAgent()
File "/home/axisrooms/.virtualenvs/ge_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fake_useragent/fake.py", line 69, in **init**
self.load()
File "/home/axisrooms/.virtualenvs/ge_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fake_useragent/fake.py", line 78, in load
verify_ssl=self.verify_ssl,
File "/home/axisrooms/.virtualenvs/ge_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 246, in load_cached
update(path, use_cache_server=use_cache_server, verify_ssl=verify_ssl)
File "/home/axisrooms/.virtualenvs/ge_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 241, in update
write(path, load(use_cache_server=use_cache_server, verify_ssl=verify_ssl))
File "/home/axisrooms/.virtualenvs/ge_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 185, in load
verify_ssl=verify_ssl,
File "/home/axisrooms/.virtualenvs/ge_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 84, in get
raise FakeUserAgentError('Maximum amount of retries reached')
FakeUserAgentError: Maximum amount of retries reached

Tried with upgrading fake-useragent and ua = UserAgent(verify_ssl=False) but still getting same error please help in this issue.

Comment: python 2 is not longer supported.